# NextJs uppercase locales redirect to lowercase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js, vercel

I work on this platform, where there are multiple locales, that we handle in the nextJs config and also through the middleware.

Currently if I do http://localhost:3000/EN-GB or http://localhost:3000/EN-GB/windows it will go to that page. For SEO purposes I would like that it gets redirects to http://localhost:3000/en-gb respectively http://localhost:3000/en-gb/windows.

I have tried multiple ways such as adding redirects in the nextJs.config.

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/DA-DK/:slug*',
        destination: '/da-dk/:slug*',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
```

Tried also some redirects in the middleware

```
  if (url.locale !== url.locale.toLowerCase()) {
    // Clone the NextURL to avoid modifying the original request.
    const newUrl = url.clone();
    // Set the new pathname to lowercase.
    newUrl.pathname = newUrl.pathname.toLowerCase()

    // Redirect to the lowercase URL.
    return NextResponse.redirect(newUrl, 301);
  }
```

Also tried to handle this client side, in the _app.js files.

I checked this tread as it is somehow similar, but it does not seem a solution has been found yet. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21498

Something that I am confused about is that if I do `console.log(router.locale)`, the locale is en-gb in the console, even though I typed http://localhost:3000/EN-GB in the browser.

So from my understanding Next.js automatically normalizes locale to lowercase, so when I type EN-GB in the browser, Next.js has already converted it to en-gb.

I guess this is why I always see the lowercase when I log to check for why this happens.

Anyone that has a similar issue or has an idea of this?

We also use AWS LoadBalancers for some different redirects. From what I read the loadBalancers do not offer the possibility to do this dynamic change, but maybe someone has an idea.